# Does this reworded question fit the rules to be not on hold?

Tags: support, specific-question, on-hold

This is a question asked by a user in Stack Overflow and was put on hold for being not clear. The question has been reworded and the objective has been narrowed down. Does it still stay in the "not clear" criteria?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810912/how-do-i-setup-mod-wsgi-to-run-python-along-with-php-in-an-apache2-server

Comment: Looks still to broad and unspecific for me.

Comment: It's definitely clearer, but (imo) that clarity just highlights the fact that it's still far too broad to be an acceptable SO question. There's no one clear, addressable problem that OP is asking for help with.

Comment: If you remove "tried alot" text from linked post there will be nothing left (ignoring possible "give me link to walk-through" which is indeed off-topic)... So why would you trying to unleash met-effect before fixing the question is beyond me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is not appropriate, no.  It provides no indication of what the problem is, what the author does and doesn't understand, what is and isn't working, etc.  Your edit has addressed none of these problems, nor can it; only the quesiton author can provide the relevant details.

It also looks like it's offtopic, as it's a system administration question, not a programming question.

Comment: Can you suggest me where this question belongs?

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee It's not appropriate anywhere.

Comment: So questions like "how to setup mod_wsgi in apache2 server to run with php?" are completely invalid? @servy

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee Yes.  That's not an appropriate question.

Comment: @coder In order for this question to be valid, the person answering it would have to be gifted with supernatural instincts, namely a crystal ball. There is nowhere near enough information provided in the question for someone to answer it. It just basically says they're trying to set up x with y, and they are having a problem. It's even more weasel-wordy than that, though, because it talks vaguely about making "them work together...in an efficient way." It's anyone's guess what that means. Or how he "messed up the server". Servy didn't say any/all questions about mod_wsgi and php are off-topic.